# I have column of URLs and need to identify which contains 'ru' (meaning russian website).But my python regex is not working

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| ID | URL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | example.ae/ru/page2 |
| 2 | example.rubin.com |
| 3 | NaN |
| 4 | example-ru/example |

I need to assign 1 to URL if it has 'ru' (I am looking for russian links), or to 0 if it is not russian.

| ID | URL | 'ru' |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | example.ae/ru/page2 | 1 |
| 2 | example.rubin.com | 0 |
| 3 | NaN | 0 |
| 4 | example-ru/example | 1 |

I used this:

```
df['URL'].str.contains(r'-ru|/ru|.ru|')  #for 1
df['URL'].str.contains(r'(?!-ru) |(?!/ru) |(?!.ru)') #for 0
```

However, this doesn't work, it still selects urls like 'example-rubin.com'

Comment: Indeed, a regex matches a substring anywhere unless you specifically add anchors or other conditions to prevent that.

Comment: `.ru` you didn't escape the dot

Comment: `r'\bru\b'` would look for `ru` with word boundaries on both sides. Your requirements are unclear, but this might at least get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: `(?!/ru) ` looks for a space which does not match `/ru` which of course it doesn't. You regexes are quite far off, so you should probably explain what you were hoping they should do.

Comment: @triplee r'\bru\b' this worked to select all urls that contain 'ru'- this was the first thing i needed. the second thing i need is to select all non-russian urls. How can I do it?

Comment: Surely, all the others?

Comment: yes, all the others

Comment: To get all other urls, simply remove the unwanted elements from your data (e.g. re.sub()) and save it into a new variable. For identification of the russian urls, have a look into regex domain verification. I'm sure you'll find a snippet on SO which you could modify to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match either `/` `.` or `-` followed by `ru` and a word boundary

```
[/.-]ru\b
```

For example:

```
df['ru'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if re.search(r'[/.-]ru\b', row['URL']) else 0 , axis=1)
```